# Почему код вызывает всплывающее окно несколько раз?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Этот код вызывает всплывающее окно несколько раз, хотя должен только один, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

```
$(".node").mouseenter (function() {
    $(".node").mouseup (function() {
        var target = "index";
        alert('Скинул');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При каждом наведении курсора на .node всем .node навешивается еще один обработчик mouseup. Вынесите функцию из mouseenter'а.